# dynamic mysql query specific value

Tags: mysql, database

i have below table

```
Overs    TargetRuns   0%    10 %    20 %    
10.0    15.6          8.7   11.9    20
10.1    15.9          8.9   12.1    20
10.2    16              9   12.2    20
10.3    16.1            9   12.3    20
10.4    16.3          9.1   12.4    20
```

my query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM target_table 
where 0% OR 10% OR 20% = '${wickets}' AND Overs = '${overs}'`
```

for overs 10.1 and 10% === 12.1
i need output as
12.1.

Comment: Overs TargetRuns 0% 10 % 20 %
10.0         15.6                 8.7 11.9         20
10.1        15.9                 8.9 12.1        20
10.2   16                  9 12.2        20      i want output as for overs 10.1 and 10%== 12.1    output===12.1

Comment: 'i have below table' I thnk that might be your first mistake.  See normalisation.

Comment: You need to quote column names which are not valid ids. Id match this regexp: `[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`. A name like 10% is not an id, so it must be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need in

```
SELECT * 
FROM target_table 
WHERE '${wickets}' IN (`0%`, `10%`, `20%`)
  AND Overs = '${overs}'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

your OR condition is wrong.

```
SELECT * 
FROM target_table 
where (0% = '${wickets}' OR 10% = '${wickets}'  OR 20% = '${wickets}') AND Overs = '${overs}'`
```